# How to post variable into controller (PHP+AJAX+MVC)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

i'm trying to post variable into php controller with ajax:

```
$(".inp_pr").keypress(function(f) {
if (f.which == 13) {
dataString = 'qwe';
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/prwrk/",
data: 'dataString=' + dataString,
success: function(data) {
alert('<?php echo($data)?>');
}
});
event.preventDefault();
}
});
```

Controller source:

```
 function action_index()
 {
 $data=$_POST['dataString'];
 $this->view->generate('prwrk_view.php', 'template_view.php',$data);
 }
```

Ajax posts variable success, but controller has no it. I think, that it will be not correct url, but it is not working with full url to controller file.

Router source:

```
class Route
{
static function start()
{

$controller_name = 'Main';
$action_name = 'index';

$routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if ( !empty($routes[1]) )
{   
    $controller_name = $routes[1];
}




if ( !empty($routes[2]) )
{
    $action_name = $routes[2];
}



$model_name = 'Model_'.$controller_name;
$controller_name = 'Controller_'.$controller_name;
$action_name = 'action_'.$action_name;



$model_file = strtolower($model_name).'.php';
$model_path = "application/models/".$model_file;
if(file_exists($model_path))
{
    include "application/models/".$model_file;
}


$controller_file = strtolower($controller_name).'.php';
$controller_path = "application/controllers/".$controller_file;
if(file_exists($controller_path))
{
    include "application/controllers/".$controller_file;
}
else
{

    Route::ErrorPage404();
}


$controller = new $controller_name;
$action = $action_name;

if(method_exists($controller, $action))
{

    $controller->$action();
}
else
{

    Route::ErrorPage404();
}

}

function ErrorPage404()
{
$host = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
header('Location:'.$host.'404');
}
}
```

How post variable to my php controller correct?

Answer (score 0):

change to this

```
data:$("#formID").serialize(),
```

and this submits the normal form submit through ajax

Comment: variable is posting, but php not returning something

Comment: change `$data=$_POST['dataString']` to this `$data=$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$(".inp_pr").keypress(function(f) {
if (f.which == 13) {
dataString = 'qwe';
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/prwrk/",
data: {dataString:dataString},
success: function(data) {
$('body').append(data);//change the body to your dom element
}
});
}
});
```

Comment: It's just refreshing my dom element.. no result

Comment: what do you mean refreshing??

Comment: i hope you have 2 routes one for the php and one for the ajax script